# KSOAP2: How to use HttpsTransportSE?

Tags: android, ksoap2

I am developing a android app to communicate with an web service that requires an SSL connection. To do that, I want to use HttpsTransportSE, but I can't find tutorials about how to use that class.
I am trying to build a new instance, but I don't know exactly the info I must pass to the constructor.
A line of my code:

HttpsTransportSE httpsTransport = new HttpsTransportSE("address", port, ????, timeout);

What string should be at ???? place?

If I replace ???? by "" or null, an IOException occurs.
I think ???? should be the client certificate. Is that right?
Does anybody have a tutorial about HttpsTransportSE? Any useful link?

Answer (score 12):

This code from the HttpsTransportSE should help:

```
public HttpsTransportSE (String host, int port, String file, int timeout) {
    super(HttpsTransportSE.PROTOCOL + "://" + host + ":" + port + file);
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port;
    this.file = file;
    this.timeout = timeout;
}
```

So to hit https://MyServer:8080/MyService
You call:

```
HttpsTransportSE("MyServer", 8080, "/MyService", timeout);
```