# KSoap and HttpsTransportSE returning URISyntaxException (Malformed IPV6 address)?

Tags: android, exception, https, ksoap

I'm trying to use HttpsTransportSE in Ksoap, but I get a URISyntaxException, saying I've got a Malformed IPV6 address- which I guess makes sense as I'm passing a URL... but how do I fix it?

I found a similar query [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811482/use-url-on-android-throws-ioexception-malformed-ipv6-address) but this relates to the Http as opposed to Https class and I don't have the overloaded method described.

I'm new to SOAP but my code so far is along the lines of:

```
    String SOAP_ACTION = "http://url.to.thingy";
String METHOD_NAME = "methodNameFromAsmx";
String NAMESPACE = "http://the.namespace";
String URL = ServerName;
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    request.addProperty("Address", UserName);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet=true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpsTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpsTransportSE(URL, 443, "/relative/pathToAsmx", 5000);
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

I've replaced the various properties with fudge for now as I'm hoping it's not relevant. My error shows the malformed IPV6 as: https:%2F%2Fmy.url.com

Comment: whats inside your `URL`?

Comment: url is simply "h t t p s : / / some.server.com" - essentially the same that's returned in the error. I don't get why it thinks it's an IPV6 address when it's not...

Comment: remove `https://` from your url and give a try, because you are already making an `HttpsTransportSE` call

Comment: Thanks - same thing happens though

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518324/ksoap2-how-to-use-httpstransportse

Comment: Thanks - that was useful. I also found an update to fix accepting all SSL certificates- so now I remove the https:// part from my URL and it fixes that error... I get a new error now, but I don't think it's related so I'll probably post another question if I get stuck!

Comment: what do you mean `update to fix accepting all SSL certificates`? how to do that?

Comment: is your new error regarding socket.closed?

Comment: It suggested I chat to avoid excessive comments but as a new member I cannot. See here for SSL fix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248147/andoird-ksoap2-https-problem  new error is a parsing error.

Answer (score 0):

Use this format,

```
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String URL = "192.168.30.8";
private static final String SERVICE = "/Wcf.WCF_.svc?wsdl";
private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/iWCF/";
```